# Selected features tool don't work in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, polygon, features, select, qgis-2.12

I work with this polygon layer and features 6 and 7 are identical:

[image]

I don't understand why the selected feature tool work when i select feature number 7

[image]

and don't work when i select feature number 6?

[image]

Note: i copy/ paste feature 7 from feature 6

I red [How to select features of visible layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72600/how-to-select-features-of-visible-layers-in-qgis?rq=1) and that didn't solved my problem.

Comment: That looks like a normal behaviour, feature 6 is probably normally selected but its just under feature 7. You can check this with "Zoom to Selection" button in main panel or attribute table. Also its possible bug, when I try to reproduce it (QGIS 2.14.6, linux Mint 18) I copy/paste a feature and only feature without geometry was created.

Answer (score 3):

The **last** feature added to your layer will always be shown at the top (i.e. it will overlap any other feature). Which is why feature 7 is shown above feature 6.

If you want to select the feature 6 instead of feature 7, you could use the **Identify Features** tool then:

1. Left-click the duplicated feature
2. Right-click the top feature (which should be feature 6)
3. Select the `Toggle feature selection` option (which should now select feature 6):

   [image: Identify features]