# Why wont QGIS let me export selected features only?

Tags: qgis, export, features

I am trying to export a specific set of soils from a state wide soil survey. However, when I try use the export selected features it wont let me use the feature?

[image]

Comment: You must actually select the features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned by @JGH, for a successful export, targeted features have to be selected. For more details about *'selecting features'*, please use [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-features).

[image: selected_features]

Comment: Thanks!  I thought just by making the layer visible it was selected. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have selected the layer as a whole. You don't have any features of that layer selected. If you want to export the layer as you are trying to do here, just go for 'Save Features As...'. If you indeed only want to select a few features (polygons), use the 'Select Features' tool. Then the feature will be enabled.

[image]

(Got the image from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72600/how-to-select-features-of-visible-layers-in-qgis))

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I was under the impression just by making the layer visible I had selected it. Thanks for your help.